# Posting Form Url Encoded body as a string

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm trying to get an access token from Discord's oauth2 token endpoint. I'm able to do it in JavaScript using the following:

```
  var bodyString = `client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code=${params['code']}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4200/callback`;

  this.http
    .post('https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token', bodyString, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    })
    .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('response from post', response);
    });
```

Notably, rather than building an object of the parameters, I had to put it into a string for it to be accepted by the endpoint.

I'm now looking to do this in C# instead. I've tried the following:

```
var body = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_id", _discordSettings.ClientId },
    {"client_secret",_discordSettings.ClientSecret},
    {"grant_type","authorization_code"},
    {"code", code},
    {"redirect_uri",redirectUrl}
};
var response = await Post<DiscordAccessTokenResponse>(_discordSettings.TokenAuthEndpoint, body);
```

where Post is defined as follows:

```
public async Task<T?> Post<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> formBody)
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(_httpClients.ToString());
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formBody) };
    var apiResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);
    if (!apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return default;
    }
    return await apiResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
}
```

But this returns:

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

This was the same error I was getting when I had to change the JavaScript approach to sending as a string. But I can't figure out how to make a similar change in C#. How can I send this `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request as a string in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Use code similar to this, to send form URL encoded data and receive tokens in a JSON response:

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");

    var credential = $"{this.configuration.ClientID}:{this.configuration.ClientSecret}";
    var basicCredential = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credential));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicCredential);

    var data = new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", this.configuration.RedirectUri),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code)
    };
                
    var response = await client.PostAsync(this.configuration.TokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw CreateOAuthError(response):
    }

    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TokenResponse>();
}
```

Where TokenResponse is a simple entity like this:

```cs
public class TokenResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; private set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; private set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; private set; }
}
```